# TFS 2010 Queries for work item hierarchies with multiple levels

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem

I've build up a hierarchical structure of all my work items with excel - all my work items are now organized in multiple levels.

User Story 1

|-- Task 1

| -- -- Sub Task 1

| -- -- -- Bug 1

| -- -- Sub Task 2

| -- -- -- Bug 2

| -- -- -- Sub Sub Task 3

| -- -- -- -- Bug 4

...

But how can I access all items under a certain work item (e.g., "All under Task 1") and visualize the results in a somehow hierarchical way?

Is this possible with TFS 2010 and VST 2010? Or do I need some third-party tools to get e.g., "All my Bugs for Sub Task 2" or "All Tasks for User Story 1"?

Thank you
Konrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you need to construct Work Item Queries in VS that have "Type of Query" equal to "Tree of Work Items".

To obtain a list of Bugs for Sub Task 2: 
New Query of type "Tree of work items" with Work Item = Sub Task 2 & linked work items Type = Bug

To obtain a list of Tasks under UStory 1: 
New Query of type "Tree of work items" with Work Item = User Story 1 & linked work items Type = Task

For an external tool:
See [here](http://visualization.codeplex.com/) for a nice codeplex-solution that generates DGML - trees of Work Items.

Comment: @Kenny: If you have the Query opened in VS and select "Edit Query", the Query editor will open up. In here there will be a "Type of Query" combobox with three available options: (1) Flat (default), (2) WIs and Direct links & (3) Tree of WIs

Comment: @pantelif – the problem for me is that the relevant TFS server is not running TFS version 2010; the new query types are only available in that version (and presumably later versions).

Comment: @pantelif Is there any general way to show 3 level relation ship in TFS queries? I have already done for two level.